# Rails 4 will_paginate on my comments article show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, will-paginate

I am having a hard time for some reason getting will_paginate gem to work with my rails blog app under my comments on the articles. I have my articles paginating perfectly fine on my index. I am trying to paginate my comments on my articles show page. I am not getting an errors and the links to the next and previous pages show up but they are only getting stuck on the first page comments when I hit next it doesn't go to next page, if that makes since. Below is my articles controller and show view. Any help is appreciative. Thanks!

```
    @comments = @article.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)

    <%= will_paginate @comments, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>

def show
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@comments = @article.comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)

@tags = Tag.all
@categories = Category.all
end

def index
@articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5).order("created_at desc")
@tags = Tag.all
@categories = Category.all
end



    <%= will_paginate @comments, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
    <%= render @article.comments %>
```

Comment: do you have enough comment records?  can you post your logs, view/controller code?

Comment: I have 6 records I created and my view and controller code are above in my question.

Comment: 6 records in total or just for that particular article?

Comment: Just for that particular article. Just weird I have the same thing on another site I built and the pagination works fine on the comments section for posts. I have the relationship and migration set up right. The comments are working fine when posting on the articles.

Comment: the reason why I asked for more of your view/controller code was to see what gets passed as your "params[:page]" (article or comment).  anyhow, the info you posted is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: Let me know what else might help and I can post it. Thanks!

Comment: can you add this code before @comments in your show action : puts "page : #{params[:page]}" and this after : puts @ comments.count.  
Then go to your articles page and show what you see in the console.

Comment: I have put that the code above in my show action before and after the @comments variable but I get nothing in the logs or console regarding the change. Any thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out!! I was rendering the comments wrong from the comments view. I originally had <% render @articles.comments %> and removed the articles part with render and it worked. Thanks for your help appreciate it.

Comment: Updated code in show view for render <%= render @comments %>